# PyQGIS: How to apply a color ramp on the symbol's outline when using QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer?

Tags: symbology, pyqgis-3, color-ramp, categorized-renderer, outline

I have polygon layer containing overlapping features (service areas for several years) and I want their symbology to

1. use a color ramp in QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer applied for each year
2. use a transparent fill and apply their former fill color to the outline.

For the first part I successfully use this code:

```
categories=[]
for u in layer.uniqueValues(fieldIndex):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    category = QgsRendererCategory(u, symbol, str(u))
    categories.append(category)

renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer("year",categories)
style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
ramp = style.colorRamp('Greens')
renderer.updateColorRamp(ramp)
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

How do I get each symbol's fill color after having applied the color ramp in order to make it the outline color for each symbol according to the ramp's gradient? Could there be a way to do so in the loop beforehand and then apply the ramp directly on the outlines?

Sidenote: I am really puzzled that using a feature's outline for symbology apparently requires some tinkering everytime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below recipe

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fieldName = 'ADM0_A3' # Change
fieldIndex = layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldName)
categories = []
for u in layer.uniqueValues(fieldIndex):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    category = QgsRendererCategory(u, symbol, str(u))
    categories.append(category)

renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(fieldName, categories)
style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
ramp = style.colorRamp('Greens')
renderer.updateColorRamp(ramp)

# The "magic" missing part
for index, category in enumerate(renderer.categories()):
    newSymbol = QgsFillSymbol()
    newSymbolLayer = newSymbol.symbolLayer(0)
    newSymbolLayer.setStrokeColor(category.symbol().symbolLayer(0).fillColor())
    newSymbolLayer.setBrushStyle(Qt.NoBrush)
    newSymbol.appendSymbolLayer(newSymbolLayer)
    renderer.updateCategorySymbol(index, newSymbol)

# Alternate solution (commented) using properties in QgsFillSymbol.createSimple
# (you need to look in keys from the qgs file, otherwise impossible to guess)
# for index, category in enumerate(renderer.categories()):
#     newSymbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({
#       'style': 'no',
#       'outline_color': category.symbol().symbolLayer(0).fillColor().name()
#     })
#     renderer.updateCategorySymbol(index, newSymbol)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After using your helpful answer may I propose two adjustments: The first is to set the fill color's alpha to zero rather than using qt.nobrush in order to keep the symbolcolor intact (for e.g.  labeling or later changes in the GUI); for the second appendSymbolLayer appears to be redundant and crashes QGIS